# How to redirect input in Powershell without BOM?

Tags: powershell, encoding, pipe, bom

I am trying to redirect input in Powershell by

```
Get-Content input.txt | my-program args
```

The problem is the piped text is preceded with a BOM (0xefbbbf), and my program cannot handle that correctly. Is there any way to redirect the input without generating a BOM, or is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you visited this page ? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content

Comment: @vssher Yes, and that does not help. There are many options specifying how to read the file, but no one to control how to pass it to the pipeline.

Comment: sometimes it helps to know which Powershell you're using, and the program accepting the lines.  Sometimes you can direct information to a program using _args_ first the to the program using __>__.

Comment: This page may help more than the last I pasted up "Write PowerShell Functions That Accept Pipelined Input" it's from 2010 but not to much has changed in the way it's done  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/write-powershell-functions-that-accept-pipelined-input/

Comment: @vssher I am using Powershell 5.1, and my program is a java program that reads stdin. I am sure that the only way to pass the data is (possibly redirected) stdin.

Comment: As I also commented on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124466/how-to-redirect-input-in-powershell-without-bom) where you posted the same question. The utility program you wrote would be much more versatile if you have it check for input prefixed with a Byte Order Mark and have it skip these bytes. As it appears, this utility now completely depends on the fact that all input should be UTF8 without BOM..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
[Console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
```

Comment: Can you provide any explanation / context for this?